# Play 2.5 replacing current.injector in Trait

Tags: scala, playframework

I am migrating my application to Play 2.5 and I have the following issue:

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi

trait Foo {
  override def reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]
  ...
}
object Foo extends Foo
```

As `current` is now deprecated, I would like to replace it. However, I can't use `@Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)` as I am in a Trait.
How am I supposed to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi

trait Foo {
  def reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi

  // other methods
}

@Singleton
class FooClass @Inject()(reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends Foo {
    // other methods
}
```

Notice how the property name in `FooClass` (`reactiveMongoApi`) matches the method defined at the trait `Foo`. After that, you can [declare a module to provide the correct bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings).

Comment: Something still confuses me, how do you create the instance of FooClass afterwards ?

Comment: Guice will handle that for you. After you [create and configure a module](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings), it is up to the DI framework to create **and** inject the required dependencies. Also, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35823086/4600